# Android SQLite MINUS query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to initialize a cursor with values from a query. The query is meant to return contents of table 1 that are not in table 2. For this I have used the `MINUS` clause but it doesnt seem to be working and I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

**Query**

```
return db.rawQuery("select _id, ingredient_name, measurement, unit from ingredients where recipe_code = " + recipe_code +
            " MINUS select ingredient_name, measurement, unit from kitchen", null);
```

**Error**

```
02-05 11:35:05.189 29028-29028/com.example.rory.prototypev2 E/AndroidRuntime: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "MINUS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select _id, ingredient_name, measurement, unit from ingredients where recipe_code = 11 MINUS select ingredient_name, measurement, unit from kitchen
```

Comment: @M D The SQL MINUS operator is used to return all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement. Each SELECT statement will define a dataset. The MINUS operator will retrieve all records from the first dataset and then remove from the results all records from the second dataset.

Comment: But`SQLite` does not support this `MINUS` kind of keyword

Comment: What would you guess suggest I used instead to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXCEPT clause instead.Which is supported in sqlite. In Docs, i cant find MINUS for sqlite

```
select _id, ingredient_name, measurement, unit from ingredients where recipe_code = " + recipe_code + " EXCEPT select ingredient_name, measurement, unit from kitchen"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator in SQLite. [SQLite Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)